# Integration of a matrix function over time with Boost / calculate the Controllability Gramian in C++

Tags: c++, boost, control-theory

I have Matrices A and B. I want to calculate the Controllability Gramian like defined on Wikipedia:
[image: Controllability Gramian]

Luckily, Boost already provides integration methods, so I wrote following function:

```
#include <boost/math/quadrature/gauss.hpp>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

typedef Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, 12, 12> GramianMatrix;

GramianMatrix calcControllabilityGramian(Eigen::Matrix<double, 12, 12> A, Eigen::Matrix<double, 12, 4> B) {
  // the integral function
  auto controllabilityGramianIntegral = [&A, &B](const double & t) -> GramianMatrix {
      return (A * t).exp() * B * B.transpose() * (A.transpose() * t).exp();
  };
  // now do the integration
  boost::math::quadrature::gauss<double, 10> integrator;
  GramianMatrix W_t = integrator.integrate(controllabilityGramianIntegral, 0.0, 1.0);

  return W_t;
}
```

It seems that Boost expects the output of this integral to be a double value and not a matrix. The compiler gives following error:
`/usr/local/include/boost/math/quadrature/gauss.hpp:1183:9: No viable conversion from 'double' to 'K' (aka 'Matrix<std::complex<double>, 12, 12>')`.
So is there a way to do this with a matrix type output? Should I use Boost or are there better libraries for this issue?
I would like to hear your suggestions!

Comment: I never tried to implement matrix values. I only got it working for real numbers and complex numbers. But I think matrix valued integrations are the natural next step.

Comment: Submit this as an issue: https://github.com/boostorg/math/issues

Comment: Add a main as well so I can see what are reasonable matrices for this problem.

Comment: I created a project on GitHub which contains everything needed to reproduce the error: https://github.com/schulz0r/Matrix-Integration. This includes the exact matrices I am working with. So far, I found out, that the odeint module of Boost is able to integrate non-scalar functions. I have to reshape my matrices to vectors in order to make it work. It is more of a workaround than a feasible solution thou.